# Class App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Auth\ForgotPasswordController does not exist

Tags: laravel-5.8

I use laravel 5.8 and I did `make:auth` and copy in web.php

**web.php**

```
Route::namespace('Auth')->group(function (){
    Route::get('login', 'LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
    Route::post('login', 'LoginController@login');
    Route::post('logout', 'LoginController@logout')->name('logout');

    if ($options['register'] ?? true) {
        Route::get('register', 'RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('register');
        Route::post('register', 'RegisterController@register');
    }

    if ($options['reset'] ?? true) {
        Route::resetPassword();
    }

    if ($options['verify'] ?? false) {
        Route::emailVerification();
    }
});
```

But I get this error

> Class App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Auth\ForgotPasswordController does not exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so the things i'd recommend checking are:

- The `ForgotPasswordController` actually exists.
- The Namespace for the controller is `App\Http\Controllers\Auth`.
- The class name of the controller is `ForgotPasswordController`.

If all are correct and true, the problem is most likely with Laravel `make:auth` setting the namespace wrong in the `web.php` routes file. Try correcting the `Route::namespace` parameter to `App\Http\Controllers\Auth` rather than just `Auth`.